# Category and Subcategories MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, heidisql

i have 3 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE student
(ID INT PRIMARYKEY NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE classA
(ID INT PRIMARYKEY NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE classB
(ID INT PRIMARYKEY NOT NULL)
```

my main category is "student". my subcategories are students from either "classA" or "classB". 
now my question is how do I implement this model in mysql? I've thought about creating an one to many relationship between student and classA and one between student and classB. Not sure if that's the best way and really realizes what i want.
i'm an major beginner and my english is pretty bad, so sorry in advance

Comment: Does each class only have one student? If each class is going to have more than one student, and each student can have multiple classes, you'd need a Many-to-Many relationship.

Comment: @PaydenK.Pringle each class can have multiple students, but a student can either be in class A or B. so he can't be in both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all about your specification :)

If a student should have many corespondents in a class table then yes you have to make one to many relationship.

A primary key in student and foreign key on the ClassA and ClassB.

Let's take a super simple example:

If a student from student table will borrow some books (an you will keep those books in ClassA table) than this is one to many relationship between student table which have one row with the student id (primary key) and classA which will have many rows with same student id (foreign key here) and the books that he borrowed :)

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for answering. so i don't want that there is more than one time the ID of a student in the classA table, every ID should be unique. so a student is either in class A or class B, but can't be in both. But in both classes there are more than one student. so should i implement an one to one relationship?

Comment: Yes if this is the case, than is one to one relationship you will have 
studentTable (studentId as primary key)-> classTableA (studentId as foreign key).
Those is one posible design another could be be that the student table will have a column with classId (let's say 1 for classA and 2 for classB)
an in this case is vice versa:

Id of the class in student table will be foreign key and id of the class in class table will be the foreign key.

Comment: if you will find this answer helpful please accept it as a answer (the check sign below the answer :) )